# PHP Pass By Refernce logic explanation

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

Can anyone explain me the output of the following PHP script:

```
        $a = array ('zero','one','two');

        foreach ($a as &$v) {
        }

        foreach ($a as $v) {
        }            

        print_r($a);
```

Output:

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => zero
>       [1] => one
>       [2] => one
>   )

Comment: Hopefully the series of downvotes on your (now deleted) question have been instructive. Discursive questions are regarded as off-topic, and if you are sharp with someone on top, you'll get more downvotes. Please be civil in this community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing by reference, you can change value inside or outside loop.

```
<?php
        $a = array ('zero','one','two');
        foreach ($a as &$v) {
        }

        // before loop $v is reference to last item in array $a
        // if you perform unset($v) before this loop, nothing will change in $a
        foreach ($a as $v) {
            // here you assigning $v values from this array in loop 
        }            

        print_r($a);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => zero
//     [1] => one
//     [2] => one
// )
```

Comment: when $v is reference to last item in array $a i.e. it is equal to two then why after seond loop last item become one

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but it may help you understand what's going on.

```
<?php

$a = array ('zero','one','two');

foreach ($a as &$v) {
}

print_r($v); // two

$v = "four";

print_r($a);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => zero
//     [1] => one
//     [2] => four
// )
```